# Excel UserForm: Multiline in label?

Tags: excel, userform

I know I could write a line of code like `Me.Label.Caption = "Line1" & vbNewLine & "Line2"` to put the caption in a label in two lines on initialization, but can I do that without writing code? Those captions are fixed, so I'd like to set them via the properties box because why write code when I don't need to? Right now my text gets cut off.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit the text directly in the label, not via the Properties pane, and use Ctrl+Enter to force a newline.

Comment: Oh God, how could I forget about the easiest option? Thank you!